# Extra fields for join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building an Web app using Rails 3.2.
I have three tables. Item, Task and Articles.

**TASK**

```
has_many :articles
has_many :items, :through => :articles
```

**ITEM**

```
has_many :articles
has_many :tasks, :through => :articles
```

**ARTICLE**

```
belongs_to :task
belongs_to :item
```

In the join table (Article) I got an extra field called amount.
How can I set this field when creating the relationship?

Right now I do it like this but it does not feel "right".

```
Article.create(item_id: self.item_id, task_id: self.id, amount: self.item_amount)
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "feel right" on your example. It is very clear that when you creating the article, you are passing the item_amount as a parameter, same thing as the other ids. I can't see a reason for refactor this code.

Comment: Ok good. Each task belongs to a project. Do you know a good way of summorizing the amounts for each articles belonging to the task (and the project)? Tried this and it´s not a good idea: sum = @project.tasks.map {|task| task.articles.sum(:price) }. To many queries.

Comment: I don't know if this query will work, but give it a try. `@project.joins(:tasks => [:articles]).sum('articles.price')`